# Asp.Net MVC 4 - ActionFilterAttribute Usage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, filtering, handle

I writted this code (CustomHandle) for application log. But, i don't want to run this code on some actions.

***CustomHandle.cs:***

```
public class CustomHandle: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        string FormVeri = "";
        string QueryVeri = "";
        foreach (var fName in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form)
        {
            FormVeri += fName + "= " + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form[fName.ToString()].ToString() + "& ";
        }
        foreach (var fQuery in filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString)
        {
            QueryVeri += fQuery + "= " + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString[fQuery.ToString()] + "& ";
        }

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

***FilterConfig.cs:***

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CustomHandle());
    }
}
```

***HomeController.cs:***

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}
```

**CustomHandle** works on **Index** and **Login**. But, **CustomHandle** is i don't want run on **Login ActionResult**.

Thanks, 
Best Regards.

Comment: You can applying filter manually on Controller you want. but error handling is done centralize mostly in FilterConfig class. else you can also do in global.asax in  Application_Error event. Best try using ELMAH for Error Logging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MVC 5... instead of adding the action filter in FilterConfig.cs

- add it to each Controller (or a base controller) - all actions will be affected.
- use [[OverrideActionFilter]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.overrideactionfiltersattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) to remove that filter for a specific action.

Example

```
    [CustomHandle]
    public class AnyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()      // has [CustomHandle] attribute
        {
        }

        [OverrideActionFilter]
        public ActionResult Login()      // ignores the [CustomHandle] attribute
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok so good, thanks. Or, can we do without ***OverrideActionFilter***?

Comment: Not really, that's why they added it to MVC 5. For earlier versions you'll just have to do it the old-fashioned way - apply the attribute to each action individually.

Comment: Oh my god. I will need to upgrade to MVC5 :((

Comment: Well! How's MVC 5?

Comment: OverrideActionFilter is for MVC 5

Comment: I updated to the latest version, thanks guys. best regards.

Answer (score 1):

When a filter is injected into a controller class, all its actions are also injected. If you would like to apply the filter only for a set of actions, you would have to inject [CustomActionFilter] to each one of them:

```
[CustomHandle]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ...
}

public ActionResult Login()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: And remove the global registration or it will run for every action in the application.

Comment: Ok thanks. But, I have over a hundred ***ActionResult***. And i will do it for all ***ActionResult***.  I need reverse logic